# Simple problem with jquery and dropdown menus (addclass, removeclass...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I currently have a problem on a website I'm developing, if you don't understand my explanation you can go directly to the website and check it by yourselves [LinkRemoved] it's about the dropdown menus.

It's a very simple jquery code, when the mouse passes over the dropdown menu link the class "open" is added to the div of the dropdown in question so that it is displayed.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header-primary ul li div a').hover(
      function() {
        $(this).parent("div").addClass("open"); //Add an active class to the anchor
      },
    )
  });
</script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header-primary ul li div ul').mouseleave(
      function() {
        $(this).parent("div").removeClass("open"); //Add an active class to the anchor
      },
    )
  });
</script>
```

Well, the problem is that if the user passes the mouse outside the dropdown sliding it towards the menu link itself, the .mouseleave although it does its function removing the "open" class when passing the link again the "open" attribute is added so the menu is displayed.

My idea is that the link has another jquery code but due to my little experience in jquery/vanilla I don't know how to do it, the link should check if the class "open" exists, if not, add it so that the menu is deployed and if the class "open" is there (the menu is deployed and the user has passed the mouse from the menu to the link) remove it to avoid the menu to stay open.

Honestly, if there is a way to do this much easier you can put it here without problem.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Hello tmrr, I made you a snippet could you add your relevant html to it. Click Edit -> Below the Snippet Click Edit above Snippet -> Paste your HTML in the left top corner.

Comment: You can use the jquery's $(this).parent("div").hasClass("open") before removing or adding the class to the parent.